# Using a while loop in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and to this website, so here goes.
I wanted to write a program that would allow as many input strings as possible to be added to an `ArrayList`. So I used a `while` loop in the following code. What I intended was for the loop to break if the input was `0`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AddToList2
{
static Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> inputlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter something here: ");
        String x = q.nextLine();
        inputlist.add(x);
        if (x.equals("0"));
            break;
    }
}
```

The program was compiled without error, but sadly, when I ran the program many times, the loop broke no matter what the input was. Any way to solve this?

Well, that was careless of me! Anyway, I had created that program in order to find out what was wrong with *this*:

```
ArrayList<String> endangeredlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> popn = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Name an animal: ");
        String animal = q.nextLine();
        endangeredlist.add(animal);
        if (animal.equals("EXTERMINATE"))
            break;          
        q.next();
        System.out.print("How many are left in the wild? ");
        int numberleft = q.nextInt();
        popn.add(new Integer(numberleft));
    }
```

(This is part of a much larger program.) My intention was for the loop to break when the animal name input was `EXTERMINATE`. Sadly the program throws a NoSuchElement exception if the input first time round was `EXTERMINATE`, and if I had inputted something else first the loop would start, but then inputting `EXTERMINATE` second time round does not break the loop. Why is that?

Comment: Instead of using ``break``, why not simply do: ``while(!x.equals("0"))``?

Comment: It would cause a compile error. Trust me, I've tried it. It's because x was initialized inside the loop.

Comment: In this case, you can use a do/while loop, like: `do { String x = q.nextLine(); } while (!x.equals("0"));`  The body of the loop can be kept the same; shortened here for readability.

Answer (score 10):

You have an extraneous semicolon after your `if`, which effectively makes it

```
if (x.equals("0")) { }
break;
```

Comment: You have the `break` statement out of the `if` body.

Comment: That's precisely the point.  His code ends up being equivalent to what is posted above, which is why it breaks regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is broken

```
if (x.equals("0"));
```

This is basically saying `if (x.equals("0"))` do nothing...

This is one of the reasons why you should use parenthesis around your `if` statements

```
if (x.equals("0")) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: - `This is why you should use parenthesis around your if statements`. No it isn't. If he'd written `if (x.equals("0")) ; { break; }` he would have had exactly the same error. We use `{ ... }` to prevent later inclusion of a second statement intended to be guarded by the `if` creating an error

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon at the end of your condition.

This turns the `break` into a statement of its own, without the condition.